# Adding values to Fishnet Grid?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, polygon, vector-grid

I have developed a fishnet grid for my study area.

I have various datasets for the area and want to allocate a value (from one of the pre-determined datasets) to each polygon within the Fishnet.

How do i display that the data from one source falls into the various polygons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use ArcGIS and need to transfer the values of features of one layer (your study data) to another layer (fishnet grid polygons), consider using the [Spatial Join](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/Spatial_Join/00080000000q000000/) geoprocessing tool.